# Change data type from varchar to enum

Tags: mysql, enums, indexing

I have a table for which I've recently changed the type of several columns from varchar to enum (see below).  My app queries against this table on both of these columns and, once the type change was made, I have seen serious performance degradation for this query (I've included the query below as well as the explain plan results).  I've so far been unable to find a culprit here and was hoping someone had run into this problem and could advise.

```
desc order_transmission_history;

+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id  | int(11)                           | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| transmission_id          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| transmitter_type         | varchar(10)  | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| initial_attempt_date     | timestamp    | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |                |
| most_recent_attempt_date | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| most_recent_status       | varchar(16)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

the index is: `KEY transmission_history_transmitter_status_date` (`transmitter_type`,`most_recent_status`,`initial_attempt_date`)

```
explain SELECT * FROM order_transmission_history where transmitter_type = 'FAX_1' AND transmission_id = '' AND (most_recent_status is null or (most_recent_status not in ('SENT', 'ERROR')));

+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type  | possible_keys                                                                             | key                                          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | transmission_history | range | transmission_history_transmitter_status_date | transmission_history_transmitter_status_date | 32      | NULL |  350 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Now, with the changed data types:

```
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field                                | Type                                                                             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id                                   | int(11)                                                                          | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| transmission_id                      | varchar(255)                                                                     | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| initial_attempt_date                 | timestamp                                                                        | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| most_recent_attempt_date             | timestamp                                                                        | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| transmitter_type                     | enum('FAX_1','FAX_2','FAX_3','EMAIL')                                            | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| most_recent_status                   | enum('NONE','PENDING','TRANSIENT_ERROR','ERROR','SENDING','SENT','SYSTEM_ERROR') | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+


explain SELECT * FROM order_transmission_history where transmitter_type = 'FAX_1' AND transmission_id = '' AND (most_recent_status is null or (most_recent_status not in ('SENT', 'ERROR')));

+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                      | type | possible_keys                                | key                                          | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | order_transmission_history | ref  | transmission_history_transmitter_status_date | transmission_history_transmitter_status_date | 2       | const | 394992 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Do you have an index on transmission_id?

Comment: Transmission_id is part of the composite index that it's attempting to use, but no I do not have an index on transmission_id by itself.

Comment: The index definition you show does not have transmission_id in it

Answer (score 0):

Since you using in your select

```
most_recent_status is null OR (most_recent_status not in ('SENT', 'ERROR'))
```

planner will not use your key. Becuase there are no way use key with such `where` clause.

So only thing it can use is

```
 transmitter_type = 'FAX_1' AND transmission_id = ''
```

but in your case planner think you have alot of lines with those values in index, so no advantage use index.

You can force use of index, but not think it will help. Probably you need think about way of rewrite your query to be more specific(for example add "order by most_recent_attempt_date  limit 10" and create key with most_recent_attempt_date first)

Also you can got more perfomance if not use null value in most_recent_status(put 'undefined' in enum) and use query which use status value instead of query which user sets ( in/not in).

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that MySQL does **not** like to use an index when you have a `where not in` or `<>` on an enum field.  Try flipping your query to check for explicit values instead.

```
SELECT * FROM order_transmission_history
where transmitter_type = 'FAX_1'
AND transmission_id = ''
AND (most_recent_status is null or
(most_recent_status in
('NONE','PENDING','TRANSIENT_ERROR','SENDING','SYSTEM_ERROR')));
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is the root cause I was looking for - the reason why my index is not being applied.

Comment: @user2957133 please consider *accepting* an answer if it has solved your problem.